# How to store part of the file name into a variable using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a file 20210823_Club_Member_Name_by_ID.txt. I want to get only the first element of the file name which is 20210823 and store it into a variable using shell script.

Currently, my code can print out the first element in the terminal but I also want to store it into a variable for further usage.

```
file='20210823_Club_Member_Name_by_ID.txt'
echo "$file" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $1}'


// I try to store it like below, but it does not work

fileDate= echo "$file" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $1}'
echo $fileDate
```

Comment: you where close, you need to "execute" the "echo "$file" as part of a command by using $() eg:```fileDate=$(echo "$file" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $1}')```

Comment: Also: `fileDate=$(echo "$file" | cut -d '_' -f1)`

Comment: `file='20210823_Club_Member_Name_by_ID.txt'; file_date="${file%%_*}"`

Comment: @Foody : Your attempt just sets the environment variable `fileDate` to the empty string and run in this context the `echo` command. Actually, the comment given by Jetchisel provides IMO the most natural solution to this task.

Answer (score 0):

As [Jetchisel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4452265/jetchisel) commented, you can use shell parameter expansion to safely extract the value. The `%%` operator removes as much of the matching text as possible, starting from the end of the string; if we use `_*` then this will essentially remove everything after and including the first underscore.

```sh
file='20210823_Club_Member_Name_by_ID.txt'
fileDate="${file%%_*}"
```

The `fileDate` variable will now contain `20210823`.

Comment: You could also use the pattern `${file%%[._]*}` to precisely implement the OP's Awk code. Don't forget to [quote the variable when you use it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)